# Docker container cannot be accessed through port 443

Tags: docker, https, tcp, port

I have running container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND      CREATED       STATUS                    PORTS                                                                                      NAMES
b48f996a91f5   pihole/pihole:latest   "/s6-init"   2 weeks ago   Up 37 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/udp, 67/udp   pihole
```

Can be accessed at `http://localhost:80/admin` but, why cannot be accessed at `https://localhost:443/admin`?, the firewall is disabled.
May be there some issues with the port 443 on my host machine so I've run some PowerShell commands:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netstat -ano|findstr 443
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13364
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1163      190.98.161.73:443      CLOSE_WAIT      7844
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1167      190.98.161.88:443      CLOSE_WAIT      7844
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1169      13.107.246.33:443      CLOSE_WAIT      7844
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1176      23.213.30.115:443      CLOSE_WAIT      7844
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1327      172.64.155.249:443     ESTABLISHED     9044
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1328      151.101.52.193:443     ESTABLISHED     9044
  TCP    192.168.1.18:1350      52.160.70.199:443      TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    192.168.1.18:6612      20.7.2.167:443         ESTABLISHED     4740
  TCP    [::]:443               [::]:0                 LISTENING       13364
  TCP    [::1]:443              [::]:0                 LISTENING       18644
```

The first and the last two lines show up when the container start running.
I'm interpreting the first and the penultimate line as the host listening for requests then forward them to port 443 of the container, I don't know what the last line does.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 443).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    353      25    26940      35392       6.25  13364  33 com.docker.backend
    147      12     1568       6764       0.14  18644  33 wslhost
```

Comment: In the docker run command there is -e flag to provide https ports, use them.

Comment: @yogihosting The container was launched with `-p` flags `-p 80:80 -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 443:443` we can see it in the running container.

Comment: Use -e flags to set environment variables for ports.